# meaning of draw line's argument in OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

I have some question about why `img` initialize like following code in document

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
```

it create a 3d array for `img`, I know 512,512 means image size, but why do we need "3" in third dimension?

Comment: The third dimension indicates the number of (color) channels, thus `3` indicates the generation of a color image (BGR, RGB, ...), whereas `1` would indicate the generation of a grayscale image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third component is used for the color channels.
In OpenCV it is default a BRG Color model.
In your example you created an Image 512x512 Pixel with 24bit color depth.
So if you just want a Gray scale image you can replace the 3 by a 1.